# Restarting SLSQP from sub iteration

Tags: openmdao

The case I am solving is two discipline aerospace problem. The architecture is IDF. I am using recorders to record the data at each iteration. I am using finite difference. I am using SLSQP optimizer from SciPy.

If after few major iteration, the optimization crashes during line search. How to start the line search from the same point?

Apart from that, I want to check whether the call to solver_nonlinear() of Component is called for purpose of derivative calculation or for line search, from inside the component. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

SLSQP doesn't offer any built in restart capability, so there isn't a whole lot you can do there. Pyopt-sparse does have some restart capability that OpenMDAO can use. Its called "hot-start" in their code.

As for knowing if a solve_nonlinear is for derivative calculations or not, I assume you mean that you want to know if the call is for an FD step or not. We don't currently have that feature.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will check with pyoptsparse.